# Find an irreducible quintic in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

> I need to find an irreducible quintic in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$

I can't seem to find any good candidate, could anyone illustrate me on how to achieve this?

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E5%2B2+mod+11) is good for generating examples.  Of course, you'll still need to prove that this example works.

Comment: Thank you! For degree 5, showing that there is not linear factor is not sufficient, is it?

Comment: Let $o$ be the order of $n\bmod 11$ then $x^k-n\bmod 11$ is irreducible iff $11\bmod ko$ has order $k$, for $k=5$ this happens iff $5| o$.

Comment: @reuns How is that proven, in a general setting?

Comment: @schrader21  No, it's not enough to show that it has no roots (unfortunately).  You need to also check that it doesn't factor as a quadratic times a cubic.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel¨I should have said $11\nmid k$. There is some $a\in \overline{\Bbb{F}}_{11}$  whose order is $ko$  and which satisfies $a^k = n$, we have $\Bbb{F}_{11}(a)=\Bbb{F}_{11^m}$, since the multiplicative group of finite fields are cyclic then $m$ is the order of $11\bmod ko$, and $x^k-n$ is irreducible iff $[\Bbb{F}_{11^m}:\Bbb{F}_{11}]=k$ iff $m=k$.

Answer (score 6):

**If you need a more elementary approach**

Let all operations be modulo $11$. All $5$ th powers are in $\{0,\pm 1\} $ and so $x^5+2$ has no linear factors.

Suppose $x^5+2=(x^2+ax+b)(x^3-ax^2+cx+d)$. Then

$$c=a^2-b$$ $$d=ab-ac$$ $$ad+bc=0$$ $$bd=2$$

Eliminating $c,d$ one obtains two equations in $a,b$ one of which is $a^4+b^2=3a^2b$ i.e. $(a^2+2b)(a^2+6b)=0$. It is now easy to check the possibilities.

Comment: "All 5 th powers are in {0,±1}" Why is this true?

Comment: This is Fermat's little theorem. If a number is not $0$ ( still using mod 11) then its 10th power is 1. Therefore its 5th power is $\pm 1$

Comment: @schrader21 $\Bbb{F}_{11}^*$ is cyclic of order $10=2\cdot5$, so there are only two distinct (non-zero) fifth powers, obviously $\pm1$.

Comment: My "go to-technique" also works. $(-2)^5=-32=1$, so $-2$ is a fifth root of unity. Therefore any zero $\alpha$ of $f(x)=x^5+2$ must be a root of unity of order $25$. If the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $m$, it belongs to the field $\Bbb{F}_{11^m}$. By Lagrange this implies that $25\mid 11^m-1$. It is trivial to check that $m=5$ is the smallest positive integer with the property $11^m\equiv1\pmod{25}$. Therefore $f(x)$ must be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, hence it is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, neat! (+) A minor tweak (by choosing $\alpha$ appropriately) would just be to say that 25 doesn't divide $11^2-1$.

Comment: Indeed. To rule out the possibility of a quadratic factor it suffices to prove that $\alpha\notin\Bbb{F}_{11^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

First show that $x^5+2$ has no linear factors because all elements raised to the fifth power must be $\in\{0,\pm1\}\bmod 11$.

To prove that there is no quadratic factor of $x^5+2$, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the two roots, or a double root taken twice, of such a quadratic factor.  Then their product $\alpha\beta$, being the constant term when the quadratic is scaled to a monic polynomial, lies in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$.  But $(\alpha\beta)^5=\alpha^5\beta^5=4$ has no such root because $4\not\in\{0,\pm1\}\bmod 11$, and like the contestants on [an old game show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Squares) I disagree.